# Preventing tizen smartwatch from going in to "watchface selection mode" when touching-and-holding watchface

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

The default behaviour for Tizen watchfaces seems to be that if you touch-and-hold anywhere on the watchface for more than 1 second, the smartwatch goes in to the watchface selection screen.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour? For example, I don't want to enter the watchface selection screen if the user does a touch-and-hold on a button element.

Comment: I would also need a touch-and-hold input for a new watch face project. Has anything changed on this? Wear OS watches bring up the watch face selection screen only when you long press on the center of the screen (like half the radius), which nicely allows for long press inputs for the watch face itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Touch and hold for 1 second" can't be overwritten/prevented.

Reason - Since if that is prevented how user will be able to change his/her watchface. So basically its a predefined platform event for changing watchface so you can't overwrite or prevent.

This is permanent behavior not default.